# WebGL: Get active texture

Tags: javascript, webgl

The WebGL function `activeTexture` allows to *set* the active texture. Is there a way to query what the active texture is?

Comment: You should try not to query WebGL (or OpenGL) except at startup/initalization. It makes your programs run slow. Search for some OpenGL performance tips and you'll see this advice often repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
gl.getParameter(gl.ACTIVE_TEXTURE);
```